# Excel: Find and delete duplicates of two columns

Tags: excel

I compare iris matching values and had each template compared to each other resulting in a table like this:

```
id1|foreign_id1| foreign_id2|values
id2|foreign_id2| foreign_id1|values
```

The values for both those entries are the same and one of them can be deleted from the table. What is the proper way to find such 'duplicates' and delete them?

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Please give an example showing which rows in which columns you would want deleted, and which must not be deleted

Comment: rephrased it a bit. The foreign key ids are the same, but switched (one time the first id was compared to the other and vice versa, but I retreive the same values from it, so one of them can be deleted)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is probably with a VBA script or macro, but here's a way to do it with straight formulas:

Concatenate the two foreign key columns into a single value, and also into a single value in reversed order.  Check if the reversed-order value exists anywhere in the list of original-order values.   (Use a character that foreign keys will never have in the concatenated string, otherwise  "XXX1"+"YYY2" will match "YYY"+"2XXX1"

Assuming your two foreign keys are in clumns B and C

Column D:
=B1&"_"&C1

Column E:
=C1&"_"&B1

Columnn that will display "0" if no matches found, "1" if 1 reverse match found:
=COUNTIF(D$1:D$999,E1)

.... You can now sort or hide based on the COUNTIF column

(if you also need to check of exact duplicates, you can change the COUNTIF range to include column E as well, and check for values > 1 (every value will have at least 1 match -- itself!)